# Use variable as the value for key of an Object - in React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, javascript-objects

**Developer Level** - I have recently started in coding languages like JS/React/React-native...

**Project Language** - React Native (with expo)

**Problem** - How do I mention a variable when calling out to values in an object.

**CODE**-

I have this Object in my `react-native` project -

```js
export const collectionItemThemes = {
    themeColor: {
        character: "245,101,101",
        actor: "218,55,55",
        drink: "255,99,71",
        food: "56,161,105",
        object: "237,137,54",
        carBrand: "56,178,172",
        action: "90,103,216",
        emotion: "159,122,234",
    }
}
```

In the main file, I **get the key stored in a variable** like -

`const theme = "character"` or
`const theme = "food"`

Now , **how do I call this variable when to using the respective value from the Object** above.

```js
type = collectionItemThemes.themeColor.**the variable goes here**
```

I have **tried the following** -

```js
themeColor = collectionItemThemes.themeColor.type
```

```js
themeColor = collectionItemThemes.themeColor.[type]
```

But these doesn't work.

Someone please help me with how the syntax goes in such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, remove the `.`. This is a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).

```
themeColor = collectionItemThemes.themeColor[type]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried `{collectionItemThemes.themeColor[key]` and it works fine.

You were trying `{collectionItemThemes.themeColor.[key]` which is wrong.

Here is my snack where i tried it;
https://snack.expo.io/@irfanwani/obj